# Does anyone know how to play the Shithead Card Game?

Tags: untagged

I tried playing the game, but the rules are too different. Each site has a different version. I found the site [www.shedgame.com](http://www.shedgame.com) and [Pagat's rules for Shithead](https://www.pagat.com/beating/shithead.html).

What should I do?

Comment: As the answer by Arcanist Lupus indicates: there is no "The" Shithead Game, there are many games that go by the name Shithead (and those games also go by other names).

Answer (score 6):

### As long as you and the people you are playing with are in agreement as to what rules you are using, it doesn't matter what those rules actually are.

Many games that have existed for a long period of time and are taught by word of mouth tend to develop variations.  But as long as all the players in one game know what rules are being applied, then the game should be fair for all players.

Some experimentation might be needed to find the ruleset that your group likes the most.  But the beauty of games is that there is no wrong set of rules, as long as the rules are applied fairly.

Remember: the goal of playing a game is for everyone involved to have fun.